# spring set Profile from external properties file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I am setting my database properties from an external file and am trying to do the same for the active profile, but am not having any luck.

In app.properties if tried: `spring.config.location= C:\\run\\secrets\\test` but that did not work.

In the same config file that I have the database properties being read in I've tried:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"file:/run/secrets/file.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class AppProperties {

 @Resource
    private Environment env;

@Bean
    public Properties props(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("spring.profiles.default", env.getRequiredProperty("spring.profiles.active"));
        //props.put("spring.profiles.active", env.getRequiredProperty("spring.profiles.active"));

        return props;
    }
}
```

In my external file I've tried both
`spring.profiles.active=dev` and `spring.profiles.default=dev`

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your file is on Disk C.

So, in windows, the external file path should be like this:

```
@PropertySource(value={"file:///C:/run/secrets/file.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```